# Measurability from taking out property of conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory

1. Two random variables $X$ and $Y$, and a sub $\sigma$-algebra
   $\mathcal G$.

   Does $\mathrm E(YX) = \mathrm E(Y \, \mathrm E(X|\mathcal G))$ imply
   $Y$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable?

   Do we need to require it hold for any $X$ in some subset?
2. If $\mathrm Y = \mathrm E(Y|\mathcal G)$ a.s., is $Y$  $\mathcal
   G$-measurable?

Thanks!

---

To Did:

The definition of conditional expectation I have been using is from p313 of Kai Lai Chung's book:

[image]

same as in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Formal_definition). I haven't changed the definition I have been using, but I might sometimes understand/use the definition improperly, which is why I ask for help here. I hope I answer your query now already, if you insist I didn't before.

Comment: It seems a comment to a previous question fully applies: "Points 1. and 2. being purely the definition forces the question: how do you define conditional expectation?" On the other page, you carefully avoided to answer this query.

Comment: Thus property (a) in KLC's textbook says that E(Y|G) is G-measurable, always, and your question 2. is whether the identity Y=E(Y|G) implies that Y is G-measurable or not. Can you explain? Note that the answer posted below basically (and rightfully) sends you back to the definitions...

Comment: For 2, I am sometimes confused for some unclear reason, so I can't explain.

Comment: Yeah well, I am not sure that asking over and over variants of the same question, whose best answer is basically "just look up the definition", will help you sort out this confusion.

Answer (score 2):

1. No. Counterexample:
   $$
   X=0; Y = \text{anything not }G\text{ measurable}
   $$
   But if it is true for any bounded r.v. this is correct (this is the definition of the conditional expectation).
2. Yes, look at the definition.

$E[X|G]$ is the only $G$ measurable r.v. such as for every $G$measurable bounded r.v. $Y$,
$$
E[XY] = E[E[X|G]Y]
$$

Comment: For 1, (1) the alternative and equivalent definition of $E(X|\mathcal G)$ requires $Y$ to be $\mathcal G$-measurable. Here, however, I ask if $Y$ is  $\mathcal G$-measurable, if it satisfies the equation in the alternative and equivalent definition of $E(X|\mathcal G)$. So I don't quite understand "if it is true for any bounded r.v. this is correct". (2) Do you have non-trivial counterexamples?